# Windows process supervisor / supervisord with web interface

Tags: windows, process-control

Problem: one of our highly hybrid app uses ~20 unix-native service's windows port (nsqd, elasticsearch, etc). Currently, this runs on a command prompt in the foreground, which doesn't strike me as particularly robust. On Ubuntu, I had great experiences with supervisord; however, latest version don't play really well with Windows anymore.

So, what specific process supervisor would you recommend for Windows?

Criteria:

- Have a web interface, with status per process, log output, and start/restart/stop controls at bare minimum
- Many apps, so configuration-file-based startup
- Would be really nice to have a console output tailing all process's aggregated output for monitoring

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found any specific packages off-the-shelf, this gist: [a lite supervisord for windows](https://gist.github.com/phuslu/5879053) fulfills criteria 2 & 3 above, and forms a good starting point for this.

Edit: gist seems down, [google cache to the rescue](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GKXL_VvHNEsJ:https://gist.github.com/phuslu/5879053%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), [codegist](http://codegists.com/snippet/python/supervisor_winpy_phuslu_python), and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/syQHFpg6)

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: See mirrors in edit

Comment: Nice, but Google cache page is still 404.